# error when usning UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle:atScrollPosition: causes my tableview to become unscrollable

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am currently trying to get my uitableview to automatically scroll to a selected cell.. I am about halfway there however when I now use this method (below) inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and its definatly centering the uitableview to the previously selected indexpath however it then dosnt allow the user to scroll the rest of the table.. it stays fixed on that position..

```
//Center previously ticked cell to center of the screen
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:oldCheckedData  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.
[image: First Select desired cell then return user to parent view]
[image: Opps, User mistake would like to change value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the one method I missed trying was the one that solved the problem... here is the answer.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //Center previously ticked cell to center of the screen
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:yourSelectedIndexMethod  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}
```